# Microba date picker for Swing, change field size

Tags: java, swing, size, jcalendar

How can I change a size of date field created by Microba Swing component? I attached a picture to illustrate what field I mean. 
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this simple code

```
 //create your DatePicker
       DatePicker picker=new DatePicker(new Date(), new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy"));
       //to change component size 
       picker.setPreferredSize(width,height)//it will work depends your layout
       //to change font and text size on picker JTextField
       picker.getComponent(0).setFont(yourFont);
```

I hope it's helpful!